# How to fetch all the events from multiple google calendar for a single google account?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console, google-people-api

I am developing an app that shows all the events from google calendar. Is there any way to get all the events from all the calendars I have in a single API?

I have checked the google API documentation and I found this API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

Here I have to choose a single calendar to fetch the events, but I have more than 6 google calendars for a single Gmail account and I really don't want to use a for loop for all calendars. So is there any way to fetch all these events from all calendars in a single API call?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `I really don't want to use a for loop for all calendars`...well there's no other option unfortunately. If there was, you'd be able to see in the documentation already

Comment: Im not sure who close voted this but how can a question about the Google calendar api be software related?

Answer (score 1):

For this you would use the [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list).

Requires that you send a calendarId.  For the method to work it needs to know which calendar you would like to see events for.

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

There is no other method for retrieving events for calendars.  You will need to loop over each of your calendars.